# Evaluation of definite elliptic integrals

Tags: calculus, elliptic-integrals

Show that definite elliptic integrals $ E_1,E_2 $

$$ E_1= \int_x^ {\pi/2} \frac {dt} {\sqrt{1-k^2 \cos^2 t } }\,, \  E_2= \int_x^{\pi/2} \frac {\cos^4 t\, dt} {\sqrt{1-k^2 \cos^2 t } }\,;$$

divide to a constant quotient independent of $x$ (when $k$ constant).

Comment: You can add some context (where you got this problem) as questions which are just problem statements are discouraged. On the other hand problems concerning transformation of elliptic integrals can have quite non-obvious solutions, but if you have tried anything you can add that here.

Comment: Thanks, @Paramanand Singh. It is my own formulation ; I was trying to modify / relate arc length to volume enclosed in an axisymmetric pressure vessel expecting  its proprtionality constant to be a Lagrange multiplier property in variational thinking. I did not post context as it is still being formulated right now and could contain minor errors; however  am reasonably clear about the physics of it from simple considerations of energy.. so posted it.

Comment: I have changed the dummy variable of integration to $t$ so that it does not conflict with the variable used in limits of integrals.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $f(x)=E_{1}(x)/E_{2}(x)$ is a constant then $f'(x) =0$ ie $$E_{1}'(x)E_{2}(x)=E_{1}(x)E_{2}'(x)$$ which is the same as $$f(x) =\frac{E_{1}(x)}{E_{2}(x)}=\frac{E_{1}'(x)}{E_{2}'(x)}$$ so that the ratio of the derivatives also equals the same constant $f(x) $. But in our case $$\frac{E_{1}'(x)}{E_{2}'(x)}=\sec^{4}(x)$$ and this is clearly not a constant. I think there is some typo or other mistake in the problem.